# Testrail Python client - SSL cert

Tags: python-3.x, testrail

I am implementing Python client for Testrail in my project (http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-python)

I am running an API call "get_test" and I am receiving an error as below

```
File "playground.py", line 10, in <module>
    case = client.send_get('get_test/53948')
  File "/Users/bhdev/Work/Python/TBH/testrail.py", line 36, in send_get
    return self.__send_request('GET', uri, None)
  File "/Users/bhdev/Work/Python/TBH/testrail.py", line 70, in __send_request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>
```

My code

```
from testrail import *


client = APIClient('https://******')
client.user = '*****'
client.password = '******'

case = client.send_get('get_test/xxxx')

print(case)
```

How could I bypass the SSL cert issue?

Comment: Try `client.send_get('get_test/xxxx', verify=False)`

Comment: Already tried that, but verify is not recognized by the server as a valid param. I switched to requests and forming my own API requests against testrail

Comment: You cannot add an extra parameter to `client.send_get()` as it only accepts the one parameter - the uri. Internally, that calls through to `__send_request()`. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your error is that the machine you are running the request on does not trust the certificate your TestRail server is using.

You can either:

- Fix the SSL Certificate on your TestRail server
- Modify the bindings (testrail.py) to disable certificate verification as per the instructions in [PEP 476 :: Opting Out](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/#opting-out)

Based on [the current python bindings source code on github](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-api/blob/master/python/3.x/testrail.py), you should be able to disable certificate verification as follows:

- Change `import json, base64` (line 14) to `import json, base64, ssl`
- Add the following line to the `__init__(self, base_url)` method

`self.context = ssl._create_unverified_context()`

- Modify the following line:

`response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()`

to pass in the unverified context.

`response = urllib.request.urlopen(request, context=self.context).read()`

Answer (score 0):

This addition solve me the problem in my case:

`import ssl`
`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`

Answer (score 0):

In "`testrail.py`", modify following line

> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

by

> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers`, verify=False`)